# how to upgrade Content Deployer?

Tags: web8, legacy-pack

I want to install Web8 with legacy features.
How can I upgrade a Content Deployer service installed as a Windows Service?
I don't want to install Discovery Service. There are any parameter for installService.ps1?
I can't see any information about Content Delivery roles as a windows service in Documentation Center, only about Java or .NET application...

2nd Edition:

I need to install a deployer that works with LocalSystem Transport.

1. I tried to install a Microservice,but I can recive a Token because I have not a Discovery Service.
2. I installed as Java application, and it works fine with HTTP transport (I need LocalSystem)
3. I compared different jars and configs between Tridion 2013 and Web8 and I think is no a good idea installing an old version of Deployer.

There would be a way to use a LocalSystem Transport on Web8. I can see configuration to use it in cd_transport_conf.xml

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everybody.
Finally I have found this page [Documentation Center](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-D070AD5F-90AC-4773-BC01-E8B67CCACB65) which lets me to use another protocols.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think it is better to setup the deployer as a Java or .NET application because it provides better flexibility and extensibility. All the legacy CD feature should just work. You shouldn't need to upgrade the deployer service to have it work with SDL Web 8

Update to your 2nd Edition:

As of SDL Web 8, the old publishing framework has been deprecated in favor of a new one, and as a result, the Publishing Management node in the Administration tab of Content Manager Explorer is hidden by default. You can make it appear again by changing a configuration setting.

Procedure
 On the Content Manager server, navigate to the folder %TRIDION%\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Configuration.
Open CME.config for editing.
Find the enablepublishingmanagement element and set its contents to true.
Save and close CME.config.
Restart the Content Manager Explorer Web site.
Access the Content Manager Explorer Web site, select the Administration tab and confirm the presence of the Publishing Management node.

After you setup your java deployer app, make sure the httpupload url works in the browser. Then use the legacy feature and create a publication target with the deployer url tied to it. The transport service should automatically pick up. No need to install a microservice nor discovery service

Comment: Thanks Robert. Yes, I did it, and I achieve to my deployer as java application works. But when i change the protocol transpor to LocalSystem, my deployer (in the same machine) does not take the packages from incoming folder.

Comment: So the transport/publisher service help generates the zip package into the /temp folder configured in the cd_transport.conf and then using the java deployer it pushes that package to the incoming folder, which is configured in the cd_deployer_conf. Can you check the folder permission of the incoming folder? Is your java app configured in another port such as 8080 and does this match in the publication target you configured? Where is it erroring out for you?

Comment: @RobertJin how did u setup legacy deployer for SDL Web8.5 .Can u please share us steps?